# can I analyze a parameter sent from a tag helper?

Tags: blazor, asp.net-core-3.1, tag-helpers

I'm working with asp net core 3.1 and in my mvc webapplication I call a razorpage with a tag helper:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-light" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Register" asp-route-id="pf">Register</button>
```

when "arrive" in RegisterModel I'd like to analyze the parameter "pf" but I don't understand how. I find a method

```
OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null)
```

and I change it so:

```
OnGetAsync(string id, string returnUrl = null)
```

but the id parameter is always null. Any assistance are appreciated very much.

Comment: Is this asp.net core mvc application or razor application? Or is it an asp.net cpre mvc application with views, controllers and from one view you are calling an razor page?

Comment: Rajdeep I work with an asp net core mvc application. The authentication is in areas/identity/pages/account path and are razor page. I call my register page from a view and I need to read a parameter.

Comment: Okay, so is it hitting breakpoint on razor page OnGetAsync method?

Comment: yes, I entered my parameter in the sign of this method

Comment: No my question is if you click button on mvc view page is it connecting to  OnGetAsync method on razor page? I don't think it's happening

Comment: ops, sorry Rajdeep. Yes, the breackpoint present in OnGetAsync method stop the application after click on button.

Comment: Can you provide more code from your view